# Unable to push the RabbitMQ logs from AWS EC2 to GCP Cloud logging service

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I have configured the cloud ops agent on EC2 to send my rabbitmq logs to GCP cloud logging, i have updated the log path and credentials in the config.yaml file, still its throwing

`windows cannot start the google cloud ops agent on the local computer - Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified`

Can someone guide me to configure and send the logs to GCP cloud logging and monitoring service.

Regards,
Dhamodharan

I have configured the aws-gcp connector project and the iam roles. now able to list the aws services in the gcp, and configured the config.yaml file with receiver and processor details along with the log file path.

Expecting the RMQ logs to be appeared in the cloud logging and monitoring service but its not visible there.